# Errors in the Logcat

Tags: java, android, json

I want to show `coordinates` of the place which the user entered in the 
    edit text and I want to use api naver platform providing.

I searched and knew that maybe I need to parse the json string in the 
    `doInBackground`.. is it right?

```
    <MainActivity.java>
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        btnShowCoord = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShowCoordinates);
        edtAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtAddress);
        txtCoord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCoordinates);

        btnShowCoord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new GetCoordinates().execute(edtAddress.getText().toString().replace(" ","+"));

            }
        });

    }
    private class GetCoordinates extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
                dialog.setMessage("Please wait....'");
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                dialog.show();
            }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String response;
            try{
                String address = strings[0];
                HttpDataHandler http = new HttpDataHandler();
                String url = String.format("https://naveropenapi.apigw.ntruss.com/map-geocode/v2/geocode",address);
               // String url = String.format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s",address);

                response = http.getHTTPData(url);
                return response;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            try{
                if(dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);


                String lat = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("addresses")).getJSONObject(0).get("x").toString();
                String lng = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("addresses")).getJSONObject(0).get("y").toString();

                //String lat = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry")
                //        .getJSONObject("location").get("lat").toString();
                //String lng = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry")
                //        .getJSONObject("location").get("lng").toString();



                txtCoord.setText(String.format("Coordinates : %s / %s", lat, lng));




            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
}




<HttpDataHandler.java>
public HttpDataHandler(){

    }
    public String getHTTPData(String requestURL)
    {
        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try{
            String addr = URLEncoder.encode("분당구 불정로 6", "UTF-8");  //주소입력
            String apiURL = "https://naveropenapi.apigw.ntruss.com/map-geocode/v2/geocode?query=분당구 불정로 6" + addr; //json
            //String apiURL = "https://openapi.naver.com/v1/map/geocode.xml?query=" + addr; // xml

            url = new URL(requestURL );
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("X-NCP-APIGW-API-KEY-ID", CLIENT_ID);
            conn.setRequestProperty("X-NCP-APIGW-API-KEY", CLIENT_SECRET);
            conn.setReadTimeout (15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-fom-urlencoded");

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    response += line;
            }
            else
                response = "";
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
}


2019-08-21 22:47:23.604 29249-29249/com.example.hermes_hg_geocoding W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
2019-08-21 22:47:23.605 29249-29249/com.example.hermes_hg_geocoding W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:460)
2019-08-21 22:47:23.606 29249-29249/com.example.hermes_hg_geocoding W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:101)
2019-08-21 22:47:23.606 29249-29249/com.example.hermes_hg_geocoding W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:164)
2019-08-21 22:47:23.606 29249-29249/com.example.hermes_hg_geocoding W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:181)
2019-08-21 22:47:23.606 29249-29249/com.example.hermes_hg_geocoding W/System.err:     at com.example.hermes_hg_geocoding.MainActivity$GetCoordinates.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:86)
2019-08-21 22:47:23.606 29249-29249/com.example.hermes_hg_geocoding W/System.err:     at com.example.hermes_hg_geocoding.MainActivity$GetCoordinates.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:49)
2019-08-21 22:47:23.606 29249-29249/com.example.hermes_hg_geocoding W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755)
2019-08-21 22:47:23.606 29249-29249/com.example.hermes_hg_geocoding W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192)
2019-08-21 22:47:23.607 29249-29249/com.example.hermes_hg_geocoding W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772)
2019-08-21 22:47:23.607 29249-29249/com.example.hermes_hg_geocoding W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
2019-08-21 22:47:23.607 29249-29249/com.example.hermes_hg_geocoding W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
2019-08-21 22:47:23.607 29249-29249/com.example.hermes_hg_geocoding W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
2019-08-21 22:47:23.607 29249-29249/com.example.hermes_hg_geocoding W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2019-08-21 22:47:23.607 29249-29249/com.example.hermes_hg_geocoding W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
2019-08-21 22:47:23.607 29249-29249/com.example.hermes_hg_geocoding W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
2019-08-21 22:47:23.646 29249-30304/com.example.hermes_hg_geocoding D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd551a120: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xd550f740)
```

Comment: `org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of `. What is value of the json string?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, its not clear to me what are you trying to ask. please describe your question clearly as to what are you trying to do and what went wrong

Comment: You are just trying to parse empty string to json object. That's why having error. Make sure you are getting the response from server.